# Static arrays in java

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am developing an app for android and for plotting a graph, I am making use of static arrays.
This is the code

```
static double[] forceatX;
int size = (int) (x+5); //where X is another input by the user
forceatX = new double[size];
int i=0;
while (i<x)
{
    forceatX[i]+=w*((x/2)-i);//where w is another input
    i++;
}
```

now the problems is that sometimes, the loop does not execute the formula in the first line and returns a ZERO value after every cycle.

However, the value of "i" increases after every cycle.

When the loop DOES execute, instead of ADDING the new value to the present value at index "i", it OVERWRITES it and assigns the new value at that index.

Any suggestion of modification to this code or a new approach will be appreciated :-)

Comment: _When the loop DOES execute, instead of ADDING the new value to the present value at index "i", it OVERWRITES it and assigns the new value at that index_ What do you mean? `forceatX` is filled with `0.0`, so obviously if you add `X` to `0`, the result will be `X`...

Comment: Could you add more information about what code is executed in a static context and what is executed in an instance context?

Comment: "first line of loop does not execute" How is that possible? I don't see any conditional statement in the loop.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, but seems to work fine here. Only thing that could go wrong tho is that `i` gets reset to 0 when the `while` loop might be called again, but that is hard to say since that part isn't shown in the code.

Comment: @all: This loop is part of an OnClick method and is supposed to add the force to an array based on the user's input. The index gives the x-axis of the graph and I want the sum of all inputs at each index, which is not happening. It is only showing the latest input, not the sum.